# hybris platformwebservices not return ar lang

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I start work with `platformwebservice`, when i hit on the URL `uri/catalogs/catalog/catalogversions/version/products/productcode` i got a list of data of product but the name is returned just in EN lang, how can I fetch a name of ar or any lang ??

Comment: Try passing  `Accept-Language` header with iso-codes as value like `ar`

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in hybris called **StoreSessionController**. This class can be used to:

- change language(for current session)
- change currency(for current session)
- change UI Experience level(for current session)

In order to change the current session language to French, for instance, you can access from the browser the following:

```
/_s/language?code=fr
```

After you accessed above URL the language session should be French and if you will try to access again `uri/catalogs/catalog/catalogversions/version/products/productcode` you should see the results in the language that you have just set on session.